# PHP DomDocument failing to handle quotes in a url

Tags: php, domdocument

When I try to open a url like that :

```
http://api.anghami.com/rest/v1/GETsearch.view?sid=11754134061397734622103190992&query=Can't Remember to Forget You Shakira&searchtype=SONG&ook&songCount=1
```

containing a quote with the browser everything works fine and the output is good as an xml

But when I try to call it from a php file:

```
        $url = "http:/api.anghami.com/rest/v1/GETsearch.view?sid=11754134061397734622103190992&query=Can't Remember to Forget You Shakira&searchtype=SONG&ook&songCount=1"

//using DOMDocument for parsing.
$data = new DOMDocument();

// loading the xml from Anghami API.
 if($data->load("$url")){// Getting the Tag song.

 foreach ($data->getElementsByTagName('song') as $searchNode)
       {
       $count++;
       $n++;
        //Getting the information of Anghami Song from the XML file.
        $valueID = $searchNode->getAttribute('id'); 
    $titleAnghami = $searchNode->getAttribute('title');
    $album = $searchNode->getAttribute('album');
    $albumID = $searchNode->getAttribute('albumID');
    $artistAnghami = $searchNode->getAttribute('artist');
    $track = $searchNode->getAttribute('track');
    $year = $searchNode->getAttribute('year');
    $coverArt = $searchNode->getAttribute('coverArt');
    $ArtistArt = $searchNode->getAttribute('ArtistArt');
    $size = $searchNode->getAttribute('size');
    }
 }
```

I get this error:

```
 'Warning: DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity    /var/www/html/http:/api.anghami.com/rest/v1/GETsearch.view?sid=11754134061397734622103190992&query=Can't Remember to Forget You Shakira&searchtype=SONG&ook&songCount=1" in /var/www/html/search.php on line 93'
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: `http://` instead of `http:/` in `$url`

Comment: Try with this url: `http://api.anghami.com/rest/v1/GETsearch.view?sid=11754134061397734622103190992&query=Can%27t%20Remember%20to%20Forget%20You%20Shakira&searchtype=SONG&ook&songCount=1`

Comment: the url is http:// ... so that's not the problem

Comment: the ur your gave me did not work !:(

Answer (score 0):

@Fracsi is correct: the URL needs to start with `http://` not `http:/`

The other problem is that the XML has a default namespace (defined with the `xmlns` attribute on the root element), so you need to use

```
$data->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://api.anghami.com/rest/v1', 'song')
```

to select all the "song" elements.